# how would I reset the counter

Tags: python

How could I make count zero after the time ends so that It could restart and ask for the user to input the password and username again? I've tried to add count = 0 at the end of the while loop and that seemed to not work ( as i thought ) then i tried to do
IF t == 0:
count = 0
after the time while loop and it didn't work. python stated that the local variable was referenced before assignment. I've changed somethings to my previous code however I'm still a bit confused on how to reset the counter. if someone could help that would be great!

```
username = input('what would you like your username to be?    ')
password = input('What would you like your password to be?    ')
  

#make sure the users password is secure
while len(password)<8:
    print("please create a stronger password it must contain 8 charaters")
    password = input('What would you like your password to be?    ')
else:
    print (" Your password is secure!")


#inputed username become new username
#inputed password becomes new password 
new_username = username
new_password = password

    
#ask user to enter username and password 
print('Enter your username and password to continue')

#the user will only have 3 chances to enter their password
count=0
while count < 3:
  #the user is asked to input their username and password
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    if password == new_password and username == new_username:
        print('Access granted')
        count += 0
        break
    else:
        print('Access denied. Try again.')
        count += 1


        
      
        
# import the time feature into program
import time

  
# define the countdown functio 
def countdown(t):
 if count == 3:   
    print ('you can try again in :')
   
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
        
     
   
  
    
 else:
  print ("welcome",new_username,"here are your files")
 
   


# the time in seconds 
t = 30

countdown(int(t))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after the time ends"?

Comment: when the timer reachers 0 seconds if the user gets the password wrong 3 times

Comment: Oh my bad, did't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# import the time feature into program
import time

username = input('what would you like your username to be?    ')
password = input('What would you like your password to be?    ')

# make sure the user's password is secure
while len(password) < 8:
    print("please create a stronger password it must contain 8 charaters")
    password = input('What would you like your password to be?    ')
else:
    print(" Your password is secure!")

# inputted username become new username
# inputted password becomes new password
new_username = username
new_password = password


def login():
    print('Enter your username and password to continue')
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        # the user is asked to input their username and password
        username = input('Enter username: ')
        password = input('Enter password: ')
        if password == new_password and username == new_username:
            print('Access granted')
            print("welcome", new_username, "here are your files")
            break
        else:
            print('Access denied. Try again.')
            count += 1
            if count == 3:
                print('you can try again in : 30 sec')
                countdown(30)


def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mints, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mints, secs)
        print(timer)
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    login()


login()
```

The program asks again and again after waiting 30 secs for every 3 incorrect entries of the user.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work fine with you you need to change the if on count to be in the access denied else section there is the code I try

```
# import the time feature into program
import time

username = input('what would you like your username to be?    ')
password = input('What would you like your password to be?    ')

# make sure the user's password is secure
while len(password) < 8:
    print("please create a stronger password it must contain 8 charaters")
    password = input('What would you like your password to be?    ')
else:
    print(" Your password is secure!")

# inputted username become new username
# inputted password becomes new password
new_username = username
new_password = password

# ask user to enter username and password
print('Enter your username and password to continue')

# the user will only have 3 chances to enter their password
count = 0
while count < 3:
    # the user is asked to input their username and password
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    if password == new_password and username == new_username:
        print('Access granted')
        exit()
    else:
        print('Access denied. Try again.')
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            print('you can try again in : 30 sec')
            exit()


# define the countdown function
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mints, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mints, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1


# the time in seconds
timer_count = 30

countdown(int(timer_count))
```